# How to share a value/variable across all pages in silverlight application

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Global file does not exist in silver light,

What would be the way to share data across pages, within the same session?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put it in a resource file and setup MergedDictionaries in your App.xaml (or just put the Data straight in your App.xaml)

```
 <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="..." />
 </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

define the data

```
 <sys:String x:Key="SingleString">Hello World</sys:String>
```

You then have access to it with with StaticResource